# Welcome to Emergency Mode! at boot time

Tags: boot, 16.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine and now I get the following error after 5 days of no problems

[image]

here is the console output for "s -alt /var/crash ":

```
total 12936
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   25007 Νοέ  23 18:28 _usr_bin_do-release-upgrade.0.crash
 drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 Νοέ  23 18:27 .
 -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 Νοέ  21 19:21 _usr_bin_unity-scope-loader.1000.uploaded
 -rw-rw-r--  1 stavros  whoopsie       0 Νοέ  21 18:12 _usr_bin_unity-scope-loader.1000.upload
 -rw-r-----  1 stavros  whoopsie 2503696 Νοέ  21 18:12 _usr_bin_unity-scope-loader.1000.crash
 -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 Νοέ  21 18:07 python3.5-minimal.0.uploaded
 -rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie       0 Νοέ  21 18:05 python3.5-minimal.0.upload
 -rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie 2042057 Νοέ  21 18:05 python3.5-minimal.0.crash
 -rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie 2306710 Νοέ  20 21:38 udev.0.crash
 -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 Νοέ  20 21:32 procps.0.uploaded
 -rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie       0 Νοέ  20 21:32 procps.0.upload
 -rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie 1986589 Νοέ  20 21:32 procps.0.crash
 -rw-r-----  1 stavros  whoopsie 4355757 Νοέ  20 18:40  _usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash
 drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root        4096 Ιούλ 19 23:54 ..
```

Comment: Are you attempting to mount any Windows/NTFS partitions in /etc/fstab at boot time?

Comment: Yes I the is drive main partition is a ntfs one but I have deleted most of the Windows's files.and I have an ssd w it's windows 10 properly shut down if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Temporarily edit /etc/fstab and comment out the Windows/NTFS mount and see if it boots normally now. Report back, and then I'll give you the next step.

Comment: How I do that ,sorry I am new to linux

Comment: Since you don't know how to do this, we'll do something different first. Check my answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In Windows:

We need to test/repair any Windows/NTFS partitions using `chkdsk`, and we need to disable `fast start` and `hibernation`.

- open an administrative command prompt window and type `chkdsk /f c:` and approve to run this at the next reboot time
- type `chkdsk /f x:` changing the "x" to any other drive letters that exist on your system
- disable `fast start` in the Power control panel

  open the `Power` control panel

  select `Change what power buttons do`

  select `Change options that are unavailable`

  uncheck `fast start`
- in the open administrative command prompt window, type `powercfg /h off`
- reboot Windows and let chkdsk test/repair the C: drive
- reboot Ubuntu and see if it boots properly

Comment: I physically removed my windows drive from the system and then problem is still there so the other partition of my ubuntu drive is creating it.this partition was a windows installation but I deleted all the windows files from it but it is stilll considered a windows boot drive so I can't;t boot from it to windows

Comment: You didn't follow my instructions. If either/both of your NTFS partitions are being mounted in Ubuntu, removing a drive will cause almost the same problem as you had to start with. Please reinstall the drive, and boot Windows and run chkdsk on all NTFS drives. If that doesn't solve the problem, then we'll try other things, but not until we bless the Windows stuff.

Comment: Hello I followed your instructions ubuntu struggles a little bit but it boots .The problem is that it boots with the screen turned of and 2-3 system program problem detected windows.

Comment: **Good, we're making progress.** Did you do **all** of the instructions that I gave you? Describe in more details the problems that you're having with Ubuntu now. Be precise. We may need to start other questions for those.

Comment: ps: Edit you answer to include the output of, using the `terminal` application: `ls -alt /var/crash`

Comment: I followed all the steps precisely

Comment: **Good**. Do you actually need Windows/NTFS partitions mounted in Ubuntu? Do you need to transfer files between the two? Show me the output of `sudo cat /etc/fstab`. And go ahead and submit the crash reports for any system program problem windows that appear. You may need to reinstall Ubuntu... but wait for my go ahead.

Comment: `# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=47b396cb-9029-4382-92be-02967757ef8b / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=01D2425F864179D0 /media/Storage ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 00
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=101AB5BD1AB5A060 /media/System_Reserved ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0
#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
UUID=1AB2B70DB2B6EC7F /media/sdb2 ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 00 `

Basicly i want only the storage partition

Comment: In `terminal`, type `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` and put a `#` in front of the lines that start with `UUID=101AB5BD1AB5A060` and `UUID=1AB2B70DB2B6EC7F`. Then reboot and make sure that only the storage drive mounts. I also notice that you don't have a swap partition identified. Any reason? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: i have 16 GB installed

Comment: Why no swap partition? Edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted view of /dev/sda, and another of /dev/sdb. Is one of these SSD? Or both HDD?